# ebay GetSellerList retrieve items by multiple specific CategoryID

Tags: ebay-api

I am developing a ebay app which is retrieving the users ebay selling items from ebay to my website. I am using a following API call for retrieving users listings which is working fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <RequesterCredentials>
       <eBayAuthToken>USER_TOKEN</eBayAuthToken>
   </RequesterCredentials>
   <CategoryID>33657</CategoryID>
   <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
   <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
   <GranularityLevel>Coarse</GranularityLevel>
   <StartTimeFrom>2018-06-28T21:59:59.005Z</StartTimeFrom>
   <StartTimeTo>2018-08-26T21:59:59.005Z</StartTimeTo>
   <IncludeWatchCount>true</IncludeWatchCount>
   <Pagination>
      <EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
   </Pagination>
   </GetSellerListRequest>
```

In current situation above API call only accepting a single category ID for retrieving seller list according to that category.

I am looking for how can I retrieve seller list items with multiple category ID. Is there any way to add multiple category ID to above API call to retrieve items according to multiple categories please help me with this 
and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well this could be achieved using findItemsAdvanced API in the finder API section of eBay

https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Request.categoryId

You can add one or more category id to the query. To limit the items are coming from your store only you also should add a Seller filter example

itemFilter(1).name=Seller&itemFilter(1).value(0)=storename

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: This call searches for items on eBay by category or keyword or both. I dont want to search an item from ebay, I want to retrieve the seller listing (person who is selling on ebay) according to specific categories.

Comment: When you provide the store name or seller name as a filter it will specifically search within that store. You can also add a list of Category Ids to narrow down the results within those categories